# FInding Value from excel sheet in python

Tags: python, xlrd, lookup-tables

I have an excel sheet (data.xlxs) with the following pattern of data with more than 200 rows.

```
NS71282379_67698209    123456001
NS71282379_56698765    123456002
NS71282379_67698209    123456003
.
.
.
```

Now in my script, I am trying to find the corresponding value for `123456003` as `NS71282379_67698209`. In my script, I want to replace 123456003 with its value from the excel sheet. 
I used `xlrd` to import the sheet but haven't found any method which easily allows me to find the corresponding value. 
How can I do this smartly?

Comment: How do the values correspond? You seem to say you have data in an excel sheet that you want to replace with the same data from the same excel sheet. Can you clarify?

Comment: You want this for all rows right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can iterate the Excel sheet by range(sheet.nrows) and get row values based on the row number. The script below iterates the Excel sheet row by row and prints out the row that matches value 123456003.  You can modify it to meet your requirement

$cat test.py

```
import xlrd

def open_file(path):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)


    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        if row_value[1] == 123456003:
            print row_value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "data.xlsx"
    open_file(path)
```

$python test.py

```
[u'NS71282379_67698209', 123456003.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to iterate over the rows and find the one you're interested in changing. Something like this:

```
for r in xrange(sheet.nrows):
  row = sheet.row(r)
  if row[0].value == "NS71282379_67698209":
    row[1].value = "new value"
    break
```

If you need to do this repeatedly, you could instead build a map from the first column values to the second column cells:

```
cells = dict((row[0].value, row[1])
             for row in (sheet.row(r) for r in xrange(sheet.nrows)))
cells["NS71282379_67698209"].value = "new value"
```