# Python code for word search in excel

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, spyder, xlrd

I need a code that can search for the specific word in excel file. In the specific columns and I want it to output with columns letter and rows number and sheet name? I have started but don't know further:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook("excel1.xlsx")
for sheet in book.sheets():
```

its needs to print row number, column letter, sheet name? also if you can use pandas instead xlrd it will be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FInding Value from excel sheet in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754941/finding-value-from-excel-sheet-in-python)

Comment: It looks like you're using the xlrd library, here's a couple worked examples https://blogs.harvard.edu/rprasad/2014/06/16/reading-excel-with-python-xlrd/  Perhaps that will help get you going.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is you may use `Pandas` library to do this. Pandas works on data frames i.e. tabular data, so have rows and columns. You need to specify your needs according to the dataset in `Pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xls')
df[df['col_name'].str.contains('ABC')].head()
df.query('col_name == ["words"]').head()
df[df['Column'] >= 'Your_search_word'].head()
```

etc. You can search more on the documentation of Pandas http://pbpython.com/excel-pandas-comp-2.html

Note: Pandas merge all sheets together to create one data frame in a tabular structure that can make things easier to search.