# Filter Excel Spreadsheet to obtain cell value with Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a GUI (shown below) and with it i want to extract a specific IP Address from an Excel spreadsheet which contains IP Address's (~1200 rows). I cannot find an example of how to search and filter the Spreadsheet to achieve what i require.

[image: GUI]

In my Spreadsheet I want to:

Search Column E for the value i enter in the GUI ie K11, which will narrow it down to ~10 Rows. I then want to search Column C for the string "Telephone" which will narrow it down to 2 Rows. I then want to extract to contents of these 2 rows in the B Column and assign each of them to variables.

Using the solution provided:

```
#Filter rows by column E (Station name) for results with cell = Asset No. (i.e "G04")
xlsx_filter1 = IP_Plan.index[IP_Plan['Station name'] == IPP2.get()].tolist()
IP_Plan=IP_Plan.loc[xlsx_filter1]

#Filter rows by column C (Type) for results with cell = Device Type (i.e "IP Telephone - Norphonic N-K1")
xlsx_filter2 = IP_Plan.index[IP_Plan['Type'] == "IP Telephone - Norphonic N-K1"].tolist()
IP_Plan=IP_Plan.loc[xlsx_filter2]

#File cell value by column B (IP address)
Output_IP_Address = IP_Plan["IP address"]
print(Output_IP_Address)
```

Produces this output upon the print command

[image]

I would like to use these two IP Addresses with my program so would like to obtain these values from the list without the index and assign them as separate variables how do i do this?

```
Output_IP_Address1 =
Output_IP_Address2 =
```

I require this so i can display the variables as a Label in the GUI (see GUI pic example shows 00.000.000.0) and use the variables in my Ping code to test and return result.

```
IP_Display_Nac = Label(IPP, text=Output_IP_Address1, anchor=W)

IP_Display_Tow = Label(IPP, text=Output_IP_Address2, anchor=W)
```

Comment: Is the data in excel in a proper table format?
Or is there any other non tabular rows etc in it too?
Can you share an example how the excel sheet looks?

Comment: Could you please provide anything that you have tried so far?

Comment: For the start you can visit [FInding Value from excel sheet in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754941/finding-value-from-excel-sheet-in-python) and then step-by-step you will collect all the answers that is required to make your program work.

Comment: unfortunately i cant share a snap of the spreadsheet due to the contents but yes proper table format. Headers at the top, columns for IP Address, Item Name, Item Description, Asset Name/Number, Mask and Gateway

Comment: `Output_IP_Address` is currently a pandas Series object. If you want your IP Adresses just use indexing: `Output_IP_Address1 =Output_IP_Address[0]` and `Output_IP_Address2 =Output_IP_Address[1]`.

Comment: @WurzelseppQX I had tried this, it only works if i type in the specific index 'code' Output_IP_Address1 =Output_IP_Address[665]  which would then work as required for Asset K11 but then when i used the tool for say Asset G05 the index would be fixed to K11's index

Comment: Oh sure, I totally forget about that... You can either cast the Series into a list: `Output_IP_Address =list( IP_Plan["IP address"])`. Or you could also try to reset the index: `Output_IP_Address = IP_Plan["IP address"].reset_index(drop=True)`. Either one will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the pandas library to import the excel file, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("nameOfYourExcelFile.xlsx")
```

The variable `df` is now a so called dataframe object that is similar to an excel table. Here is some small headstart how to work with pandas Data Frames:

```
df.head()
```

this gives you the first few rows of the dataframe, by this you can check the structure of the dataframe and the names of the columns, for example.

```
df["Name of the desired Column"] # gives you the complete desired column as a vector
```

This only applies if you have headers in your column, like that:

[image]

In this example `df["a"]` would be `[5,9,2,3]`.
If you have no headers in your file, then just import the excel file like so:

```
df = pd.read_excel("nameOfYourExcelFile.xlsx", header=None)
```

and call your column by a numbered index starting at 0, so column A would be `df[0]` and column E would be `df[4]`, etc...

Other helpful functions:

```
df.iloc[1,:] # gives you the complete row with index 1
df.iloc[1,2] # gives you the item in row with index 1 and column with index 2
list(df) # gives you a list of all column header, in case you are in doubt which to take
```

---

#### Now here some example code how you could achieve your result:

```
indices_first_check = df.index[df['Name of your column E'] == "K11"].tolist()
```

This gives you a list of all row indices where the value in column E is "K11".
Then you can slice all other rows off:

```
df = df.iloc[indices_first_check,:]
```

Now get the indices for the "Telephone":
    indices_second_check = df.index[df['Name of your column C'] == "Telephone"].tolist()
    df = df.iloc[indices_second_check,:]

Now you can have your 2 desired values within a list:

```
list_desired_values = list(df["Name of your column B"])
```

Hope this helps.

edit: Changed last line so that Dataframe Column (Pandas Series object) ist being casted to a list.

Comment: Thank for the comprehensive answer and for breaking it down for me. I had been trying to achieve this with openPyxl with no joy.

In regards to filtering rows for the value does the cell have to match exactly? i.e would "Telephone" still return the row if the cell = "Telephone Model ABC-123")

Comment: Yes, this method is only working when it is matching exactly. The only solution I could spontaneously think of to solve this would be to `colList = df["Name of Column"]` and then iterate through it `for item in colList:` and check for the substring "Telephone" with `if item.find("Telephone")>-1:` and then get the row index of this item by `index = df.index[df["columnName"]==item].tolist()`, etc... But this is quite messy, because you should only have strings in your column as `.find()` is only working with strings, so you need to make an assertion, etc...

Comment: when run using .iloc it returned 'error positional indicators out of bounds' i managed to get this code working using .loc instead which returned the results as intended.

Comment: At Present the result is printed together and including the index

787   10.123.4.5
788   10.123.4.6

I would like to get these values separate i.e as IP_1= and IP_2=  how is this possible ???

Comment: When you say "printed together" can you give an example how you print it? If you really mean printing, you can do something like this with separating strings:`print("IP_1=",list_desired_values[0],"IP_2=",list_desired_values[1])` or with one string: `print("IP_1= {} IP_2= {}".format(list_desired_values[0], list_desired_values[1])`

Comment: I have added an image of the output to the question and edited the question to reflect what i want to achieve